# Disk errors during boot, failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED

Tags: boot, disk, sata

Ubuntu boot takes long time, and on boot I get these errors:

[image]

Similar errors appear on shutdown (which is also slow), however Windows 10 on the same SSD boots normally. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but that fixed nothing and same errors occur when I boot from live USB. What's the problem and how can I try to fix it?

Comment: This is likely a hardware problem with your disk. In the best case, it might be a loose or broken cable which needs to be replaced, but I also heard of other seemingly unrelated damaged components like power supplies being able to cause this. Worst case, the drive itself or a disk controlling component on the mainboard might be broken. First step I'd check the disk's SMART status (open e.g. Gnome Disks in Ubuntu or use `smartctl` from the terminal) and run a disk self-test. You can also try unplugging the disk and replugging it e.g. in a different socket and with a different cable.

Comment: It could however also e.g. be a disk controller that doesn't work well with Linux, or maybe something fixable by a BIOS/firmware update.... Please [edit] your question and add the SMART status values and self-test results of the disk, maybe we know more then.